# How to Prove a function is not absolutely summable

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone please help prove that this function is not absolutely summable. I know this function is not summable because it is not defined at infinity I just don't know how to prove it's not absolutely summable.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\sin\frac{2n\pi}6\right|$$

Thanks in advance, sorry if I don't add all of the correct tags, I am tagging this with convolution because that is the problem I am trying to solve after gaining the proof for this function, feel free to edit as applicable!

Comment: It's not a function. It's a series. Hint: $a_n$ doesn't converge to zero.

Comment: Well, if $f(n)=\left\vert\sin\frac{2n\pi}6\right\vert$, then for all $n$, $f(n+3)=f(n)$. Moreover, $f(1)>0$, so...

Comment: "Not defined at infinity" isn't a meaningful phrase in this context. Moreover, because the terms of this series are already nonnegative, absolutely summable is exactly the same as summable. Can you review the definition of a series being summable? and (as Botnakov N. hints) review the Test for Divergence?

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ is not convergent, then it is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: I've tried for a couple of hours now and it doesn't seem like I'm applying the test for divergence correctly given sin...

Comment: Can someone please help, I've got an exam coming soon and would really appreciate anyone providing an answer